# PHP substr Persian string end with question mark

Tags: php

In PHP when I want to `substr` the Persian string 'حروف فارسی برای امتحان', and it appends the question mark at the end of string.

This is my code:

`$a = 'حروف فارسی برای امتحان';
echo substr($a,0,10);`

And the problem is `حروف �`

Anyone has any suggestion or solution for this regards? much appreciated.

Comment: You should be using `mb_substr()` instead of `substr()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `mb_substr($a,0,10,'utf-8')` instead of substr() for Persian and Arabic characters

Answer (score 2):

PHP does not have multi-byte character support by default. You have to use mb_* functions, like

```
mb_substr()
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php